# How to get rid of my spamming notification?

Tags: software-update, notifications, mediaplayer

The DivX player has installed a junk notification on my Mac saying:

> A new version of DivX is available.

as shown below:

[image: A new version of DivX is available - Update Now / What's New]

This stupid notification bumps up every hour or so, and there is no way to turn it off (there's no disable option when I click on it's icon). I don't want and don't need their software. I can't see the player in my *Notification panel*.

[image]

**Question:** How to prevent DivX from spamming me with notifications?

Comment: Updating is an option? Or don't you need Divx?

Comment: @Rob I don't have the software. I removed it. I don't want to install a new version because I don't need it. DivX is spamming old users to improve their market share.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Removing DivX and DivXUpdate

If you'd like to remove the DivX app along with its DivXUpdate, you need to uninstall the software.

### Uninstaller

Uninstaller you can find in `/Applications/DivX` folder and run `Uninstall DivX for Mac.app`.

### Manual Removal

If above folder and uninstaller doesn't exist, just remove:

```
/Library/Application Support/DivX/DivXUpdate.app
```

To remove the associated `launchd` services, check first which one are registered by this Terminal command:

```
launchctl list | grep divx
```

Then `disable` or `remove` them. The following two commands will remove the jobs:

```
launchctl remove com.divx.update.agent
launchctl remove com.divx.dms.agent
```

After you may consider removing these service files from `/Library/LaunchAgents` (called `divx`).

```
sudo rm /Library/LaunchAgents/com.divx.update.agent.plist # For Update
sudo rm /Library/LaunchAgents/com.divx.dms.agent.plist # For DivXMediaServer
```

### Killing notification popup

Then kill the annoying update app, type this command in Terminal:

```
killall DivXUpdate
```